# WebSocket in golang

Tags: go, websocket, http-headers

I am trying to convert a Python websocket client connection string to Golang. This is the Python code

```py
from websocket import create_connection

connection_string = "ws:// 10.1.2.3/socket{0}".format(token)

ws = create_connection(connection_string, sslopt={"check_hostname": False})
```

I have created the same in Golang, as below:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/nexus", nexus).Methods("POST")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":12345", router))
}

func nexus(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    flag.Parse()

    interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

    token := "GkZl5NLRZJl5+jqChouaZ9CYjgE58W/pMccR+LeXmdO0obG9NBIwo1VBo7+YC1oiJL9mS6I9qh62BkX+Xddhe0JYrTmSG4JcKZ4t3bcP2Mxy3VBmgoJjwZ76ZOuf9V9AD6Xl83lyoR4bLBzqbSSU1R2NIgUotCGWjZt5JX6CJF0="

    socketUrl := "wss://" + "10.1.2.3" + "/socket" + fmt.Sprintf(token)

    log.Println("Connecting to nexus event channel...")
    config := tls.Config{}
    dialer := websocket.Dialer{
        TLSClientConfig: &config,
    }
    //check_hostname:=false
    //request.Header.Add("check_hostname","false")
    conn, _, err := dialer.Dial(socketUrl, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dial:", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    done := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        defer close(done)
        for {
            _, message, err := conn.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("read:", err)
                return
            }
            log.Printf("recv: %s", message)
        }
    }()

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            return
        case t := <-ticker.C:
            err := conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(t.String()))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("write:", err)
                return
            }
        case <-interrupt:
            log.Println("interrupt")

            // Cleanly close the connection by sending a close message and then
            // waiting (with timeout) for the server to close the connection.
            err := conn.WriteMessage(websocket.CloseMessage, websocket.FormatCloseMessage(websocket.CloseNormalClosure, ""))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("write close:", err)
                return
            }
            select {
            case <-done:
            case <-time.After(time.Second):
            }
            return
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to call it from the client, I am getting the error:

```
time="2021-10-07T12:45:22+05:30" level=info msg="Connecting to nexus event channel..."
time="2021-10-07T12:45:43+05:30" level=fatal msg="dial:dial tcp 10.1.2.3:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

Process finished with the exit code 1
```

Per my understanding, it's failing because of sslopt in the URL string.  Any go reference code will helpful to resolve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the target port is 443.
2. The `socketUrl` looks different from `connection_string = "ws:// 10.1.2.3/socket{0}".format(token)`, `wss` or `ws`.

I tried to connect a [server](https://gowebexamples.com/websockets/) using your code, it worked if i change `wss` to `ws`.

```
p1gd0g$ gor main.go
INFO[0000] Connecting to nexus event channel...         
INFO[0001] recv: 2021-10-08 21:13:36.7483105 +0800 CST m=+1.001602801 
INFO[0002] recv: 2021-10-08 21:13:37.748889 +0800 CST m=+2.002181301 
INFO[0003] recv: 2021-10-08 21:13:38.7482128 +0800 CST m=+3.001505101 
INFO[0004] recv: 2021-10-08 21:13:39.74902 +0800 CST m=+4.002312301 
INFO[0005] recv: 2021-10-08 21:13:40.74893 +0800 CST m=+5.002222501 
^CINFO[0005] interrupt                                    
INFO[0005] read: websocket: close 1000 (normal)
```